# How do you go about sending a discord embed as a response after command triggers to update user on command status?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently attempting to learn discord.py. I'm coming from discord.js so it's a huge change, but something I'm wanting to learn in unison. The documentation for discord.py is a little confusing. Basically what I created is a discord bot that sends viewers to an Ebay listing to help with sales and the bot works overall, but it only works with sending a standard message as a response and I'm wanting to change that with the bot responding with an embed. Below is my current code and the # comments is the embed I'm wanting to send.

````
import requests
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

token = ""

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="-views [number of views] [link]")
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-", intents = intents, activity=activity, status=discord.Status.idle)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if '-views' in message.content:
        number_of_views = message.content.split(' ')[1]
        link = message.content.split(' ')[2]

    response=f'Sending {number_of_views} viewers to {link}!'
    await message.channel.send(response)


    #response = discord.Embed(description="Sent {number_of_views} viewers!\nProduct Link\n{link}", color=0x2B2F51)
    #response.set_footer(text = "Flex Offenders", icon_url = "https://i.imgur.com/KbKB5gk.png")
    #message.channel.send(embed=response)

    for i in range(int(number_of_views)):
            requests.get(link)

    response= f'{number_of_views} viewers have been sent to {link}!'
    await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(token)

#async def on_message(message):
    #embedSend = discord.Embed(description='Sending {number_of_views} viewers!\nProduct Link\n{link}', color=0x2B2F51)
    #embedSend.set_footer(text = "Flex Offenders", icon_url = "https://i.imgur.com/KbKB5gk.png")
    #message.channel.send(embed=embedSend)```

I tried replacing the response=f to response = discord.Embed to see if I can trigger an embed as a response that way. I also tried removing response entirely and it was embedSend = discord.Embed and both ways didn't seem to trigger the embed to send as a response.
````

Comment: send has only one positional parameter, content. That is for plain text. To send the embed you would have to pass it with the keyword. send(embed=response).

Comment: also send() has always have to be awaited

Comment: for any further help please include your error message(s)